# Create SQL User Defined Types in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, user-defined-types

How to create a user defined type in SQL Server using VS2012?
I tried to do the step shown in the image but no thing appears.

[image]

Also I have tried to create Type using the following code but I can not create elements of that type in my table.

```
CREATE TYPE CartListType AS TABLE 
(
   [ItemNo]   INT            NOT NULL,
   [NameEn]   NVARCHAR (150) NULL,
   [Price]    FLOAT (53)     NULL,
   [Quantity] INT            NULL,
   [ImageSrc] VARCHAR (100)  NULL
)
```

Comment: The code you've shown works fine for me. So not sure what your issue is. "I can not create elements of that type" - can you show that attempt?

Comment: This what I am trying to do >> http://imgur.com/iPtc4nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of nested tables in SQL Server. So whilst the code you've shown is correct for declaring a user-defined table (UDT) type, what you cannot do is then use that type as the declared type of a column in another table. All you can use UDTs for are for variable and parameter declarations<sup>1</sup>.

The more relational thing to do would be to just create this as a normal table with an additional column to act as a foreign key back to the `Bills` table. An alternative, if you really do want to store the data "in-row" (although it'll actually be stored in separate pages physically) would be to declare the column as XML, and use the XML facilities instead to store and manipulate this data.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've said something with certainty, so someone's bound to pop up and mention some third use case I've forgotten, but the general point stands.

Comment: Using that type as a column wouldn't be a "nested table" - at least not in the sense as it is used in Oracle. It would be a column based on a "struct", i.e. a single value with "sub-values". A nested table (as used in Oracle) would be able to store multiple *rows* of that UDT. But I agree that this is better done through a 1:N relationship

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it seemed to resemble Oracle's nested tables to me. And we don't know whether the OP was intending to store 0, 1 or multiple rows in this column, for each outer row, if they'd have succeeded in creating this table

Comment: you are right, after a closer look at the UDT, Hamed most probably wanted to create a "nested table".